# Turn string to unique id between 2 numbers

Tags: java, string, math, hash, integer

How would you convert a string to a unique integer between two values? In a way that it would always return the same number for the same string

For example if i had this string "Hello world" it would need to be converted to an unique number between 0 and 15. And then if the string was different it would be converted to a different number between 0 and 15 but the same string would always convert to the same number

You can get the hash code which is just an integer from a string in java with string.hashCode(). Maybe that could be used to generate it somehow.

Comment: Note that there are only 16 different integers between 0 and 15, but there are far more than 16 possible different strings. So, a general hashing algorithm can't guarantee that two different strings will have different ids.

Comment: If you want an integer hash value x between integers a and b, so that a <= x < b, then compute h'(x) = a + h(x) mod (b - a), where h(x) is whatever hash function you like, for example x.hashCode().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.hashCode() % 15;` would get you a number in [0, 14]. If 15 needs to be an option, then you could do `string.hashCode() % 16;` instead.

Comment: One thing to note, `string.hashCode()` can be negative.